# How to prevent console output after exiting the program

Tags: c++, windows, command-line, terminal, dos

I'm writing simple command-line program in C++ (windows). One functionality of it is to check keyboard input and if a certain key is pressed, exit the program.

Actually it works fine so far, however when the program exits, I get all the pressed key on the output of the command-line? Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: actually I want to do it in standard C++ or at least with WIN32 API, so getch does not fit, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `_kbhit()` to test if a key is pressed. and when it is use `_getch()` to get the value. (note `_getch()` can return `0` or `0xE0` for special keys and call `_getch()` again for that value)

Comment: OK, I suppose there is no way to do it 'native' way with the standard C/C++. The way you proposed it, works quite fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

`getch` has no echo, meaning it does not print the character you type. Here is some more info about all the get char functions in C/C++:

http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread37195.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on *how* you check for keyboard input.

You probably check for the input without actually using it, thus leaving it in the input queue for the next program able to get it (the command line).

Comment: I use GetAsyncKeyState, so probably you are right? Can you propose something? Thx

Comment: As you know that there's something on the input, you can use `char c; std::cin >> c;`

Comment: Yes, that's right, however it still produces output on the terminal. Besides that it always awaits the RETURN key, without it it does not even exit the prog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getch() which is supposed not to echo the character. I can't remember the header in which it's defined, but I think it was conio.h (remember that it's not a standard header)